# How do I create a sticky header (scrolls along x-axis) and sidebar (scrolls along y-axis), which scroll with the page content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a list of content with a sticky header and sticky sidebar.

As I scroll down the page content, I want the sidebar to scroll down too.
As I scroll left and right on the page, I want the header to scroll along with it.

Much like this - http://tv.sky.com/tv-guide

I want time along the header and screens down the sidebar but can't figure out what CSS to apply to achieve this.

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="timeline">


   <ul>
      <li>&nbsp;</li>
      <li>|10am</li>
      <li>|10am</li>
      <li>|11am</li>
      <li>|12pm</li>
      <li>|1pm</li>
      <li>|2pm</li>
      <li>|3pm</li>
      <li>|4pm</li>
      <li>|5pm</li>
      <li>|6pm</li>
      <li>|7pm</li>
      <li>|8pm</li>
      <li>|9pm</li>
      <li>|10pm</li>
      <li>|11pm</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="screens">
    <ul>
      <li>Screen 1</li>
      <li>Screen 2</li>
      <li>Screen 3</li>
      <li>Screen 4</li>
      <li>Screen 5</li>
      <li>Screen 6</li>
      <li>Screen 7</li>
      <li>Screen 8</li>
      <li>Screen 9</li>
      <li>Screen 10</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just apply this rule to any element you want `position: fixed;` and use `top: somepixel` `left: somepixel` `right:somepixel` `bottom:somepixel` to control the position of the element and use `overflow-x` and and `overflow-y` rules to control the scroll along their respective directions